# jQuery Javascript ratings: Making the rating reappear when user takes their cursor off

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jQuery code that handles hovering over rating stars, when you hover they glow as they're meant to. Problem is, once you've taken your cursor out, it still displays what your cursor was on (and doesn't show the original rating). How can I make it check for when the cursor is removed, then show the original ratings?

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $("[id^=rating_]").hover(function() {


        rid = $(this).attr("id").split("_")[1];
        $("#rating_"+rid).children("[class^=star_]").children('img').hover(function() {

            $("#rating_"+rid).children("[class^=star_]").children('img').removeClass("hover");

            /* The hovered item number */
            var hovered = $(this).parent().attr("class").split("_")[1];

            while(hovered > 0) {
                $("#rating_"+rid).children(".star_"+hovered).children('img').addClass("hover");
                hovered--;
            }

        });
    });

    $("[id^=rating_]").children("[class^=star_]").click(function() {

        var current_star = $(this).attr("class").split("_")[1];
        var rid = $(this).parent().attr("id").split("_")[1];

        $('#rating_'+rid).load('http://localhost:8888/fivestars/send.php', {rating: current_star, id: rid});

    });




});
```

EDIT: Outputted HTML for something with a 3-star rating:

```
<div id="rating_3">
            <span class="star_1"><img src="http://localhost:8888/fivestars/star_blank.png" alt="" class="hover" /></span>
            <span class="star_2"><img src="http://localhost:8888/fivestars/star_blank.png" alt="" class="hover" /></span>
            <span class="star_3"><img src="http://localhost:8888/fivestars/star_blank.png" alt="" class="hover" /></span>
            <span class="star_4"><img src="http://localhost:8888/fivestars/star_blank.png" alt=""  /></span>
            <span class="star_5"><img src="http://localhost:8888/fivestars/star_blank.png" alt=""  /></span>
        </div>
```

Comment: @Jack - Do you still have the 'inner' `hover` as your code currently shows? Calling hover with a function as a parameter doesn't trigger the event. It assigns a handler to the element. Usually this is done only once, not every time you hover.

Comment: OK, I haven't really changed the code much - but I'm sorry, I'm not really a JS coder. How would I change this?

Comment: I've edited my answer. I assume that as you hover over each 'star', you want that one, and the ones before it to receive the 'hover' class, and the ones after it to have the 'hover' class removed.

Comment: Sorry, I missed where you asked for it to retain the original rating. I'll update again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

The selected rating is stored in the ratings_x element's `data()`, and is retrieved when you leave the ratings area.

```
    $('[class^=star_]').mouseenter(
        function() {
            if($(this).parent().data('selected') == undefined) {
                var selectedStar = $(this).parent().find('.hover').length - 1;
                $(this).parent().data('selected', selectedStar)
            }
            $(this).children().addClass('hover');
            $(this).prevAll().children().addClass('hover');
            $(this).nextAll().children().removeClass('hover');
        });

    $('[id^=rating_]').mouseleave(
        function() {
            var selectedIndex = $(this).data('selected')
            var $selected = $(this).find('img').eq(selectedIndex).addClass('hover').parent();
            $selected.prevAll().children().addClass('hover');
            $selected.nextAll().children().removeClass('hover');
    });
```

---

The proper usage of `hover()` is with two functions:

```
$('#myElement').hover(
    function() {
        // mouseenter code
    },
    function() {
        // mouseleave code
    }
);
```

Use the second function to set the proper view when the mouse leaves the element.

Answer (score 2):

The hover event works as follow in Jquery:

```
$("[id^=rating_]").hover(function() {
//IN
},
function() {
 //OUT
 //Your code when the cursor is out here.
});
```

From your code, I can conclude that your Out code will probably look like this :

```
$("id^=rating_").children("[class^=star_]").children('img').removeClass("hover");
```

Comment: Great answer - I'm sorry if I sound like I'm asking for it on a plate, but I'm not a JS coder... the Out code doesn't work, it seems to make no difference... any further ideas? :)

Comment: OK, I'm a step closer:  $("[id^=rating_]"). needed square brackets. Now they show 0 stars when the cursor is removed. I guess I just need to get the value originally now?